# AWS CloudFormation error on additional Service creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, continuous-deployment

I am working on a project where we need to deploy

1. Production - server and client
2. Staging - server and client.

We used AWS CF to deploy the production server and client - which worked successfully.
However, on attempting to deploy the staging server and client, we get a CREATE_FAILED status on the client staging nested stack with

> Logical ID - Service
>
> Type - AWS::ECS::Service

and error

> [Stack name here]Service-2MCMYC2EFDWZ did not stabilize.

As this was happening, staging server constantly got created successfully on each attempt to update the stack.
Since the update fails, it gets rolled back as expected.

We then attempted to push the staging services one at a time - starting with staging server - which got created and is accessible.

We proceeded to push changes for the staging client which got created, but it failed once again on creating the **Service** resource of type **AWS::ECS::Service** on the staging server - not entirely sure why it tried creating a new resource on an already existing nested stack.
This caused the *UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED* status and we rolled back the service by excluding the failing resource.

I have made a similar CF template with the same options for our project - excluding private details :D. You can [find it here](https://gitlab.com/twumm/aws-cf-tf).

I will appreciate if I can get what I need to change to make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved this by increasing the ECS ClusterSize. I had 4 initially. 8 did the trick.
Placing tasks were unsuccessful because the container could not meet its requirements. It also had insufficient memory. This subsequently caused the service to not stabilize.